# Как перевести unix время в дату

Tags: java, android

Как перевести `unix` время в `обычную дату`, а также (если получится) сделать разницу между датами, и сделать такой конвертер чтобы на выходе был массив и с помощью этого массива можно было сделать такой текст

`прошло 0 дней, 6 минут, 54 секунды, от указаной и до другой указаной даты.`

Comment: Слишком много для одного вопроса. И подробнее описывайте конкретную задачу.

Comment: «Обычная дата» — неопределенное понятие. Объект какого класса вы имеете в виду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть много методов, вот некоторые

вариант №1

```
Calendar mydate = Calendar.getInstance();
mydate.setTimeInMillis(timestamp*1000);
out.println(mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+
    mydate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"."+
    mydate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

вариант №2

```
long unixSeconds = 1372339860; // секунды
Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L); // *1000 получаем миллисекунды
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); // какой формат нужен, выбераем
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4")); // если нужно даем таймзон
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Для разницы, просто берете разницу миллисекунд (или timestamp.gettime()) и форматируете с помоью `Calendar`

Comment: а SimpleDateFormat() что за функция? где её смотреть?

Comment: @cyklop77 тут http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html и https://www.javatpoint.com/java-simpledateformat